# Failed to include nib to my expressjs/nodejs site?

Tags: node.js, express, nib

I followed the example [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/nib) to add nib to my site:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , nib = require('nib');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'your secret here' }));
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(nib());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

But when I start the server I get this error:

```
500 TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'include'
at Object.handle (/home/alex/apps/foo/node_modules/nib/lib/nib.js:51:11)
at next (/home/alex/apps/foo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:201:15)
at Object.handle (/home/alex/apps/foo/node_modules/stylus/lib/middleware.js:187:7)
at next (/home/alex/apps/foo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:201:15)
at /home/alex/apps/foo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:323:9
at /home/alex/apps/foo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:342:9
at Array.0 (/home/alex/apps/foo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:52:9)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your "development" mode since you don't want to have stylus compiling at run time in a production environment:

```
app.configure('development', function(){
  var stylusMiddleware = stylus.middleware({
  src: __dirname + '/stylus/', // .styl files are located in `/stylus`
  dest: __dirname + '/public/', // .styl resources are compiled `/css/*.css`
  debug: true,
  compile: function(str, path) { // optional, but recommended
    return stylus(str)
      .set('filename', path)
      .set('warn', true)
      .set('compress', true)
      .use(nib());
    }
  });
  app.use(stylusMiddleware);  
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express['static'](__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

that's my usual setup with nib and stylus.  and with this set up you'd need to move up your `require("stylus")` to the top as `stylus = require("stylus")`, similar to your `require("nib")`.

you will have to have your general `configure` method list after the `development` one.